# TextView scrolling stops abruptly when I stop. How can I make it keep going and slow to a stop?

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, textview

TextView scrolling stops abruptly when I stop.  How can I make it keep going and slow to a stop, like most real apps.

This is the code I added:

```
        String s = readTextFile(inputStream);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tv.setText(s);
```

And in the XML:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Comment: Please include more context.  Consider adding Activity/Fragment code or layout xml code, etc...

Comment: I added code in OP.   No momentum scrolling seems to be the default, yet every app ever made does this, so I assume this has got to be asked at least 10 times a day.

Comment: Turns out I needed "ScrollView". Simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed "ScrollView".  Simple answer.